# Windshield wipers worked intermittently then quit altogether

Tags: electrical, mazda, windshield-wipers

The wipers on my 2000 Mazda Protege recently quit working.  It wasn't an all-of-a-sudden thing, though.  Every so often over the last few weeks they would stop for a few seconds, then start again.  Then last week they were working when I left the house and quit halfway to work, only to start again when I wiggled the wiper arms.  Then this weekend they quit entirely.  When they were working, there was no indication that anything was wrong (speed normal, cleared mild amount of snow, etc).

I've had wiper motors fail before (struggled to move the wipers before quitting) and a switch solenoid (worked one day then not the next).  Any ideas on what I should check given the gradually-failing method this one took?  Since this just happened, and it's 10°F outside right now, I have not dug under the hood at all yet.

The washer pump is still working (made for an interesting experience on the highway when the wipers quit).  To me that would indicate that the fuse is probably still good, unless someone knows if they are on separate circuits.

Comment: The water pump and wipers will definitely be on different circuits and will therefore have separate fuses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up looking at it yesterday.  I pulled the wire harness out of the motor to start inspecting things and when I plugged it back in it worked for a moment.  Scraped some of the dirt and corrosion off of the connecting blades and it seems to work fine now.  Must have had just enough connection to work, but was susceptible to losing connectivity by vibration from driving.